# How to process firebase short dynamic link Onsuccess result

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this method in Xamarin Android that creates firebase shortdynamic link:

```
private void GetDynamicLink()
        {

            string uid = "My_Id";
            string link = "https://ledrop.com/?invitedby=" + uid;
        var task =    FirebaseDynamicLinks.Instance.CreateDynamicLink()
        .SetLink(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(link))
        .SetDynamicLinkDomain("ledrop.page.link")
        .SetAndroidParameters(
                new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder(PackageName)
                        .SetMinimumVersion(125)
                        .Build()).BuildShortDynamicLink().AddOnSuccessListener(this, new dynamicLinkListener());


        }
```

I Attached an onsuccess listener as shown above, then i process the listener like this:

```
internal class dynamicLinkListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnSuccessListener, IOnFailureListener
        {


            public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
            {

                var sDynamicLink = result as IShortDynamicLink;

            }

        }
```

But the sDynamicLink variable returns null, how do i get the shortLink from the result?

Comment: Hi @Tolulope, Did you find any solution to retrieve the deep link from the result in Xamarin. Can you please share the process or links which you followed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @RanjithKumarNagiri No i didn't, I think its a bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use JavaCast, like this

```
class OnSuccessListner : Java.Lang.Object, IOnSuccessListener
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> _tcs;

    public OnSuccessListner(TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs)
    {
        _tcs = tcs;
    }

    void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        var link = result.JavaCast<IShortDynamicLink>();
        _tcs.TrySetResult(link.ShortLink.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, will try it out and give feedback

Comment: This works great and btw you could also await the Task and use JavaCast on the result instead of using the IOnSuccessListener to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I too have the same problem, so I have resolved it by using rest api call to get the dynamic short url

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest

POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key (present in firebase settings web API)
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "dynamicLinkDomain": "example.page.link",
    "link": "https://www.example.com/",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "com.example.android"
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "com.example.ios"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thanks but I'll prefer to use the xamarin android api. The returned object is of class "com.google.gms.zzeab" and i cant convert it to short link